# Remove categories taxonomy from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I've got a custom post type called "Resources".

**How I've defined the taxonomy:**

```
register_taxonomy(  
    'resource',  // the name of the taxonomy
    'resources', // post type name
    array(  
        'hierarchical' => true,  
        //'label' => 'Resources',  // display name
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'resources', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front' => false // Don't display the category base before 
        )
    )  
);
```

**How I've registered the post type:**

```
register_post_type(
            'resources',
            tp_build_post_args(
                'resources', 'Resource', 'Resources',
                array(
                    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
                    'menu_position' => 20,
                    'has_archive'   => true,
                    'public'      => true,
                    'supports' => array('editor', 'title','author','thumbnail', 'revisions'),
                    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'type', 'sector')
                )
            )
        );
```

As you can see, I do not have the `category` option selected in `'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'type', 'sector')`, but it is appearing as an option in the admin:

[image]

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I believe that "Categories" is actually for the custom taxonomy `resource` and not the standard `category` taxonomy. But in the menu, it's labeled `Categories` because you didn't set a custom label for the `resource` taxonomy (because the `label` is commented out and defaults to `Categories`):

```php
register_taxonomy(
    'resource',  // the name of the taxonomy
    'resources', // post type name
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        //'label' => 'Resources',  // display name <- this
        ...
    )
);
```

Secondly, the `resource` taxonomy is actually assigned to the `resources` post type, despite the taxonomy is not in the list of the post type's `taxonomies` property:

```php
register_taxonomy(
    'resource',  // the name of the taxonomy
    'resources', // post type name <- here, the taxonomy will be assigned to this post type
    array( ... )
);
```

If you don't actually want the `resource` taxonomy to be assigned to the `resources` post type, then either set the post type to `null` or whatever the proper post type is:

```php
register_taxonomy(
    'resource',  // the name of the taxonomy
    null,        // set to null, which means don't assign to `resources` or any post types..
    array( ... )
);
```

Alternatively, you can use `unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type()` to un-assign the taxonomy from a post type:

```php
// Call after the post type and taxonomy are both registered.
unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'resource', 'resources' );
```

Comment: Hi Sally, apologies, was caught up with other stuff. But yes, you have solved my issue, wasn't aware that it defaults to "Categories" if no label is defined - thanks for the comments too!

Comment: Glad it helped. :) And you should probably know that the default label is `Categories` only if the taxonomy is hierarchical; if it's not hierarchical, then the label defaults to `Tags`.